# SQL Server query fast after clearing cache

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a problem with a query running on Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

This query selects articles out of different stores and ran fine over months, within under one second.

Several weeks ago, this query suddenly started taking a very long time to finish - 50 seconds or more - but only for one of our stores.

If I clear the query plan cache for this one `SELECT` statement, then the query takes less than one second to finish again.

Unfortunately, this problem occurs only very sporadically and only on our productive server, so I have no chance to analyze the problem.

I restarted the server few weeks ago and the problem did not occur until yesterday (before every three days).

Do you have any idea or tip for me to solve this problem?

Comment: parameter sniffing? clearing the cache isn't a good idea on production. If its quick for all bar one then look at the distribution of rows in the statistics. Have a read of this: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/08/start-troubleshooting-parameter-sniffing-issues/

Comment: a matter of of statistics update ?

Comment: Parameter sniffing at a guess, canonical reading on this subject: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely looks like a parameter sniffing issue.

[Read more about Parameter Sniffing](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2011/11/06/what-is-parameter-sniffing/)

You can try following options.

1-  Use Dummy variables on SQL Server stored procedure or function used.

2-  Alter SP WITH RECOMPILE Option.

3-  Use hints like OPTION(RECOMPILE) or OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@VARIABLE=VALUE))

4-  Disable Parameter sniffing on SQL instance.

You can read more about this on MSDN for recommendation and workarounds [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-possible-workarounds/)